# How to send byte array with processing

Tags: processing

I'm new to processing. I've made some GUI in Processing and I need to send some bytes to another MCU via Serial port to control LEDs. I need to send this code A0 0C 01 A2.

```
byte on[]={0xA0, 0x0C, 0x01, 0xA2}; 
port.write(on); 
//This won't compile
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, just need to use the Processing syntax (not the Arduino one) for the [byte](https://processing.org/reference/byte.html) array:

```
byte[] on = {(byte)0xA0, (byte)0x0C, (byte)0x01, (byte)0xA2};
```